# Why does vim show yellow boxes at the end of lines when I use putty?

Tags: vim, centos, putty

I'm using putty v0.63 and I'm logged into a CentOS 6.5 server.

Vim looks like this:

[image: vim putty yellow EOL]

How can I make Vim not show yellow line endings?

Comment: You probably searched from something. that matches at the end of lines. For example `/$`

Comment: does command `:noh` help?

Comment: It does! So searches persist throughout opening and closing vim. lol

Answer (score 4):

You've searched for something that matches the end of all lines, probably `/$`.

Vim remembers the last search pattern (in fact, the entire history), see `:help viminfo`.

You can clear the search highlighting via

```
:nohlsearch
```

The next search, or search motions like `n` and `N` will automatically turn on highlighting again.

If you don't want Vim to start with highlighting, put the above command into your `~/.vimrc`, or clear the last search pattern via

```
:let @/ = ''
```